# Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author] on linkedin ugcPost

Tags: linkedin-api

Getting Error: Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]

I have the "w_organization_social" permission in my app. I'm successfully getting the access token.

Can anyone help me what's going wrong?

**Url:** https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts

**Body:**

```
{
    "author":"urn:li:person:<id>",
    "lifecycleState":"PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text":"Hello world"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO",
            "media":[{
                "status":"READY",
                "description": {
                    "text":"hello world"
                },
                "media":"urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:<asset_id>",
                "title":{
                    "text":"hello world"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "visibility":{
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility":"PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

**Response**:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode" : 100,
    "message" : "Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]",
    "status" : 403
}
```

Comment: Contact Linkedin developer's support

Comment: I'm trying to debug a similar issue, so I'm confused as well! However, I do notice that you're requesting a permission for working with an organization (`w_organization_social`), but your body seems to reference a "Person ID" (`urn:li:person:<id>`). Are you trying to post to a user's profile (`w_member_social` permission) or an organization page (`w_organization_social` permission)?

Comment: For any others this may help, our particular problem was that it turns out that we forgot to update our auth code to request the `w_organization_social` permission. That's our bad. But LinkedIn, you've really got to step up your game. Really - how hard would it be to return an error message like, "This action requires the w_organization_social permission scope."?

Comment: Extremely VALUABLE detail that saved from waste an unpredictable number of hours of my life!

Answer (score 3):

While getting access token, make sure that you pass *r_liteprofile* and *w_member_social* permissions in *scope*.

Then you have to send a GET request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me, to get the Lite Profile and you will get the **ID** from the response.

Use the **ID** you got from Lite Profile to generate Person URN,
eg: `"urn:li:person:<ID>"`

Answer (score 0):

From original Microsoft doc : [Common Creation Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http)

- Code: 403
- Message: Not enough permissions to access: POST {endpoint}
- Description: Indicates the token used has not been scoped to the correct permissions. Generate a new token with w_organization_social or w_member_social.